# How poptoroot ViewController when tapping on tabbaritem in Tabview swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

I want to poptoroot ViewController when tapping on tabbaritem in Tabview swiftui
In swiftui the default tabview doesn't support that functionality.
I have researched for this questions many times but still can't find the solution, because none of the solutions works for me.
this is my code example that I use for creating tabview.
TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
firstTab
.tabItem { TabViewTab(activeTab: $activeTab, tab: .orange) }
.tag(TabItem.first)

```
        secondTab
            .tabItem { TabViewTab(activeTab: $activeTab, tab: .service) }
            .tag(TabItem.second)
        
        thirdTab
            .tabItem { TabViewTab(activeTab: $activeTab, tab: .timetable) }
            .tag(TabItem.third)

        forthTab
            .tabItem { TabViewTab(activeTab: $activeTab, tab: .more) }
            .tag(TabItem.forth)
    }
```

Please if you have any working solution help)
Thanks

Comment: Two options: use `NavigationStack` with `NavigationPath` in each of your tabview and you can pop to root view by clearing the path. Or your can try this `https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect` to access UIKit interfaces.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, Navigationstack works only from iOS 16, and introspect method not working when I add this method.
.introspectTabBarController { tabBarController in
    if let navController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
        navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
} @QuangHà